# "unkown chipset" error trying to install ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: 22.04, dell, usb-installation, nouveau

I bought a brand new Dell XPS 8960 which is preloaded with windows.  I tried to install ubuntu on it by following direction found here:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#4-boot-from-usb-flash-drive

I created a bootable USB stick using balenaEtcher and this seemed to work.  However, when I boot up (<kbd>F12</kbd>) from the USB stick, it just hangs with a blank screen and gives the message:

> 1.435792  nouveau 0000:01:000.0: unknown chipset (196000a1)

I can't seem to go any further.  Anyone know what to do?
Judith

Comment: What video card/chip? Nouveau is the open source driver that really only works for older cards/chips. Have you tried Safe Boot which uses nomodeset as boot parameter? And then during install be sure to install optional restricted proprietary driver to get correct nVidia driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

Once I tried ubuntu in safe graphics mode, it installed -- (however part way through, I had to go back to windows and turn off BitLocker in order to proceed with a dual boot). On rebooting, it still hung until I tried installing under "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then going into recovery mode, then resume normal boot.
From a terminal, then did (this took some time)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Once the drivers were updated, a normal reboot worked fine, meaning that it wasn't necessary to go to advanced options or recovery mode.